# Saving passwords for pages that redirect on login ( Chrome and FF )

Tags: linux, firefox, google-chrome, password-management

There are pages which redirect after successful login.

It makes impossible to click on "save password" prompt.

How to save passwords for such websites in convenient way ?

( Chrome , Firefox )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have luck w/this in Firefox

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saved-password-editor/