# How to edit FF passwords without extensions (directly in FF config files)?

Tags: firefox, password-management, sqlite

How to edit FireFox passwords manually ?

Here I've been given answer how to do this with extension:

[Saving passwords for pages that redirect on login ( Chrome and FF )](https://superuser.com/questions/462032/saving-passwords-for-pages-that-redirect-on-login-chrome-and-ff/)

How to do this without extension ?
Most data are kept in FF as SQlite databases, so there is no problem in editing them in SQlite.
Is there similar way for FF with password for security device ?

Comment: Passwords which need to be retrieved, such as passwords saved in Firefox, should be stored encrypted. Presuming this, there is not likely any way you can directly edit them outside of Firefox's built-in mechanisms or a plugin which is granted access.

Comment: Not necessary - I would bet it uses some well tested, available external cryptography components, like DB. As with DB, thanks to that FF uses well tested available SQlite, it's easy to edit this with external tools. I assume it must be the same with cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [master password](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Master_password):

> Firefox: "Tools -> Options -> Security / Passwords -> Use a master password"

It is editable via the following process:

> Firefox: "Tools -> Options -> Security / Passwords -> Change Master Password"

Otherwise, if it's a SmartCard device, the [webCrypto](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) API may be what you're looking for:

> Warning: The features mentioned in this article are proprietary Mozilla extensions, and are not supported in any other browser.

Beyond that, [NSS Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Tools) may be what you're looking for:

> Software developed by the Mozilla.org projects traditionally used its own implementation of security protocols and cryptographic algorithms, originally called Netscape Security Services, nowadays called Network Security Services (NSS). NSS is a library written in the C programming language. It's free and open source software, and many other software projects have decided to use it. In order to support multiple operating systems (OS), it is based on a cross platform portability layer, called the Netscape Portable Runtime (NSPR), which provides cross platform application programming interfaces (APIs) for OS specific APIs like file system access, memory management, network communication, and multithreaded programming.